# How to update SpeedView inside ListView without initial animation?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

So I have a fragment with three speedview gauges in it. [Picture of fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSgWt.png) They used to be in the fragment directly and would work fine, but after I needed to add the textviews, I couldn't get everything to fit on the screen so I decided to  create a custom layout and use a list view to display them.

It used to be very easy to update the speedometers and everythign worked fine.

After adding everything to a listview the only way I can think to get everything to update is to use notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter, but when I do this, the gauge indicator snaps to 0 and goes up to the desired number from there. I have tried using a holder to maybe fix the problem, but no luck.

This is the fragment's code on how I create the adapter

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        OEEsegmentList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.OEEplusLV);

        qualitySegment = new OEEListSegment("Quality", OEEqualityValueString, "Bad parts: "+OEEqualityBadPartsValueString, "Total parts: "+OEEqualityTotalPartsValueString);
        availabilitySegment = new OEEListSegment("Availability", OEEavailabilityValueString, "Downtime: "+OEEavailabilityDowntimeValueString, "Next time: "+OEEavailabilityNextTimeValueString);
        performanceSegment = new OEEListSegment("Performance", OEEperformanceValueString, "Act time: "+OEEperformanceActTimeValueString, "Takt time: "+OEEperformanceTaktTimeValueString);

        OEEsegmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        OEEsegmentArrayList.add(qualitySegment);
        OEEsegmentArrayList.add(availabilitySegment);
        OEEsegmentArrayList.add(performanceSegment);

        OEEadapter = new OEEListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.oee_list_layout, OEEsegmentArrayList);
        OEEsegmentList.setAdapter(OEEadapter);

    }
```

and here is one of the update functions, they're all basically the same code with different names. I call them in the main activity when I recieve a message about the particular marker being changed.

```
public void updateOEEplusAvailability (String availability) {
        OEEavailabilityValueString=availability;

        availabilitySegment.setSegmentValueDial(OEEavailabilityValueString);

        OEEadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

this is my entire list adapter

```
public class OEEListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OEEListSegment> {
    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    public ArrayList<OEEListSegment> mSegments ;

    public OEEListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<OEEListSegment> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mSegments=objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        String name = getItem(position).getSegmentName();
        String valueDial = getItem(position).getSegmentValueDial();
        String valueTV1 = getItem(position).getSegmentValueTV1();
        String valueTV2 = getItem(position).getSegmentValueTV2();

        final OEEListSegment Segment = new OEEListSegment(name, valueDial, valueTV1, valueTV2);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSegmentName);

        holder.speedView = (SpeedView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.segmentSpeedView);
        holder.textViewFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSegmentFirst);
        holder.textViewSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSegmentSecond);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.textViewFirst.setText(mSegments.get(position).getSegmentValueTV1());
        holder.textViewSecond.setText(mSegments.get(position).getSegmentValueTV2());
        holder.speedView.speedTo(Float.parseFloat(mSegments.get(position).getSegmentValueDial()));


        holder.speedView.clearSections();
        holder.speedView.addSections(
                new Section(.3f, Color.RED)
                , new Section(.7f, Color.YELLOW)
                , new Section(1f, Color.GREEN));


        textViewName.setText(name);
        holder.textViewFirst.setText(valueTV1);
        holder.textViewSecond.setText(valueTV2);
        holder.speedView.speedTo(Float.parseFloat(valueDial));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSegments.size();
    }

    public Object getItemCustom(int position) {
        return mSegments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        protected SpeedView speedView ;
        private TextView textViewFirst ;
        private TextView textViewSecond;

    }
}
```

And this is the list segment code

```
public class OEEListSegment implements  Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String valueDial;
    private String valueTV1;
    private String valueTV2;

    public OEEListSegment(String name, String valueDial, String valueTV1, String valueTV2) {
        this.name=name;
        this.valueDial=valueDial;
        this.valueTV1=valueTV1;
        this.valueTV2=valueTV2;
    }

    public String getSegmentName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setSegmentName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getSegmentValueDial() {
        return valueDial;
    }
    public void setSegmentValueDial(String valueDial) {
        this.valueDial=valueDial;
    }

    public String getSegmentValueTV1() {
        return valueTV1;
    }
    public void setSegmentValueTV1(String valueTV1) {
        this.valueTV1=valueTV1;
    }

    public String getSegmentValueTV2() {
        return valueTV2;
    }
    public void setSegmentValueTV2(String valueTV2) {
        this.valueTV2=valueTV2;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.name, this.valueDial, this.valueTV1, this.valueTV2});
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        valueDial= in.readString();
        valueTV1= in.readString();
        valueTV2= in.readString();
    }

    public OEEListSegment(Parcel in){
        String[] data = new String[4];

        in.readStringArray(data);
        // the order needs to be the same as in writeToParcel() method
        this.name = data[0];
        this.valueDial= data[1];
        this.valueTV1= data[2];
        this.valueTV2= data[3];
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public OEEListSegment createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new OEEListSegment(in);
        }

        public OEEListSegment[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OEEListSegment[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Any solution would be appreciated. Either how to stop that initial animation (0 to desired number) from happening in the speed view or how to update the listview so that animation doesn't happen.

Or would it be best to omit the list view completely, while still getting this desired layout (there will only ever be 3 segments).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do what I needed to do inside the list segment, but since I knew the exact number of times I wanted this segment to be shown, I decided to change my approach.

I added a scoll view in my main layout and then included the segment layout 3x inside it. I then needed to access all the components by ID  like  this to acces the segment (layout)

```
performanceLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.performanceSegment);
```

and like this to access the elements inside my segments

```
speedViewPerformance= performanceLayout.findViewById(R.id.segmentSpeedView);
```

then I could update the speeviews with funcktions like this

```
 public void updateOEEplusPerformance (String performance) {
    OEEperformanceValueString=performance;
    speedViewPerformance.speedTo(Float.parseFloat(OEEperformanceValueString));
}
```

It's much simpler than what I was trying to do before, since I don't need an adapter  or a new class, I definitely do not need to change the speedview animation and it works just like I needed it to!